# AWS CLI create ECR repo

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-ecr

I am trying to create a ECR repo with list of tags from the AWS cli. This is the command I am running. I need to pass in the tags as JSON

```
aws ecr create-repository \
    --repository-name alpha/sample-repo \
    --region us-west-2 \
    --tags [{"Key":"env","Value":"dev"},{"Key":"team","Value":"finance"}]
```

and getting the below error

```
Error parsing parameter '--tags': Invalid JSON:
[Key:env]
```

what am i missing here? How to make it work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try enclosing the `tags` with a single quote

```
aws ecr create-repository \
    --repository-name alpha/sample-repo \
    --region us-west-2 \
    --tags '[{"Key":"env","Value":"dev"},{"Key":"team","Value":"finance"}]'
```